# Last 6 Fridays from Today

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

This is quite a specific one, I need the dates of the last 6 Fridays in C#.NET. Currently we are completing this task by having a SQL Database with a table full of the dates of the Friday's in the year.

This has two issues,

1) It seems an unnecessary query to the database when I'm pretty sure C# can do it.

2) I have to remember at the end of the year to add in the next year.

I've had a look around the net and i'm sure theres a post somewhere thats showing me the answer clearly, but I can't seem to find it!

I'm hoping someone can help me with the code for this question.

Many Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Calendar class does this very well : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.aspx

Comment: Maybe I just misunderstood you, but you need "nearest 6 Fridays *before* today" or "nearest 6 Fridays *after* today?" Also, are we ignoring Today, if it is Friday now?

Comment: It's the 6 Friday's before today and if today is Friday then that will be one of the 6.

Answer (score 5):

Main idea is to choose a first friday before today and step one week at a time:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime nearestFridayBeforeToday;

if(now.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Friday)
{
    nearestFridayBeforeToday = now.AddDays(DayOfWeek.Friday - now.DayOfWeek) //returns first friday after today
                                  .AddDays(-7); //so we need to subtract one week
}
else
{
    nearestFridayBeforeToday = now;
}

var sixFridaysBeforeNow = Enumerable.Range(0, 6)
                                    .Select(n => nearestFridayBeforeToday.AddDays(-7 * n));

//print results 
var r = sixFridaysBeforeNow.Select(d => string.Format("{0} : {1}", d, d.DayOfWeek));
Console.WriteLine (string.Join(Environment.NewLine, r));
```

prints:

```
6/21/2013 3:37:52 PM : Friday
6/14/2013 3:37:52 PM : Friday
6/7/2013 3:37:52 PM : Friday
5/31/2013 3:37:52 PM : Friday
5/24/2013 3:37:52 PM : Friday
5/17/2013 3:37:52 PM : Friday
```

Comment: This isn't going to have good results if today is Friday or Saturday.

Comment: Almost, but not quite there... Check the logic around when you should subtract the week.  Compare my answer if you need a hint. :-)

Comment: @MattJohnson why? we only need to subtract, when it's now friday now. If it is - we need to start from today and count six weeks

Comment: If today is *Saturday*, you'll subtract the week and skip over yesterday, which should have been in the list.

Answer (score 3):

The `DateTime` struct has a property called [`DayOfWeek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek.aspx). It is an enumeration telling you the day of the week corresponding to that instance of a `DateTime`.

So you could write some code like this:

```
List<DateTime> sixFridays = new List<DateTime>();
DateTime foo = DateTime.Today;

while (sixFridays.Count < 6) {
    if (foo.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday) sixFridays.Add(foo);
    foo = foo.AddDays(-1);
}
```

That'll get you six fridays before today. If you want six fridays after today, just add 1 days instead of -1 in the loop.

@Damien_The_Unbeliever suggested a less brute forced approach. Here it goes:

```
List<DateTime> sixFridays = new List<DateTime>();
DateTime foo = DateTime.Today;

while (foo.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Friday) {
    foo = foo.AddDays(-1);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 6; foo.AddDays(-7)) {
    sixFridays.Add(foo);
    i++; // I don't remember if you could place this together with foo.AddDays(-7) in the last part of the command.
}
```

**Edited** since the OP said he wants to include the current day in case it's a friday too, also it's six fridays before today.

Comment: Don't you think, after you've identified the first Friday, there might be an opportunity to, maybe, compute all of the other Fridays immediately from it, rather than looping?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yep. There's even an answer like that, which I upvoted. It's just that this is a 20 seconds solution. One can always refine. If it were a more complex problem, I sure wouldn't use a brute force solution such as the one I propose.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an extension method you can use.

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> Last(this DayOfWeek dow, int count)
{
    var today = DateTime.Today;
    var adjustment = today.DayOfWeek - dow + (dow > today.DayOfWeek ? 7 : 0);
    return Enumerable.Range(0, count)
                     .Select(x => today.AddDays(x * -7 - adjustment));
}
```

Call it like this:

```
var last6Fridays = DayOfWeek.Friday.Last(6);
```

For example:

```
var last6Fridays = DayOfWeek.Friday.Last(6);
var formatted = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                            last6Fridays.Select(x => x.ToLongDateString()));
Console.WriteLine(formatted);
```

**Output:**

> Friday, June 21, 2013
>   Friday, June 14, 2013
>   Friday, June 7, 2013
>   Friday, May 31, 2013
>   Friday, May 24, 2013
>   Friday, May 17, 2013

Answer (score 1):

You can try this also

```
 private List<DateTime> GetLastFridays()
 {

        List<DateTime> lstLastFridays = new List<DateTime>();
        TimeSpan oTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(((int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek + 2), 0, 0, 0, 0);
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.Subtract(oTimeSpan);

        lstLastFridays.Add(dt);

        for (int count = 0; count < 6; count++)
        {
            dt = dt.Subtract(new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0, 0));
            lstLastFridays.Add(dt);
        }

        return lstLastFridays;

 }
```

Comment: ignoring other details, I want to suggest to use `TimeSpan.FromDays(7)` instead of `new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0, 0)` - it makes code much more readable.

Comment: You could also use `DateTime.AddDays`. I think it's more intuitive.